# Setting a connect timeout with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, pdo

I'm using PDO to get data off a MySQL server. What I noticed is this: if the MySQL server is unavailable, it takes *really* (relatively) long for this code to return an exception:

```
try {
  $handle = new PDO($db_type . ':host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_user,$db_pass);
  // Tried using PDO::setAttribute and PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT here
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage;
}
```

In case of MySQL it takes just over 2 minutes for the exception to occur (SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on...) and 30 seconds on PostgreSQL (SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired).

I tried using PDO::setAttribute and PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT but it's not working. Which I guess makes sense, since the problem occurs before this statement.

Is there a way to set a timeout for connecting to the DB? 2 minutes/30 seconds seems really long to me for PDO to realize there is nothing there.

I think I saw this being done somewhere, but can't find it again for the life of me.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
$DBH = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", 
    $username, 
    $password,
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 5, // in seconds
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was after. I would expect this to be mentioned somewhere [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

Comment: Thanks also. Working with french public administration servers sucks :D

Comment: By the way, the time is specified in seconds. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php for more info

Comment: One thing to note on this is you need to set the PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT inside the PDO instantiation. If you try and use something like `$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 10)` after the instantiation, it will not work!

Comment: i had try this setting PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 60, change to a IP not valid but it not working.Time out occur after 20s

Comment: Notice, the PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT only appears to effect the connection time and not the statement time on mysql.

Comment: Exciting! I am using Drupal, where this exact case is documented here: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1309278#comment-5284590

Answer (score 10):

I'm using the DBLIB driver for PDO - and that doesn't support the passing of options (throws a warning).

To get round this, you can edit the `connection_timeout` setting in the FreeTDS config file which is located at `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf` (on Ubuntu).

Comment: On OSX, mine was located at `/usr/local/etc/freetds.conf`

Comment: I'm using DBLIB (pdo_dblib PHP extension), and passing attributes works. `new PDO("dblib:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass, $attributes)`