# How to increase the connection timeout using PHPwith dblib using PDO?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, database-connection

In a connection with a external server (**MS SQL SERVER**), in another system (other software dealer) which I integrate another data, and that is very very slow, with this, the connection result in error.

How to increase the timeout of the connection **dblib** com **PDO**?

I tried to use  `array(\PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 10)` in options of PDO connection, but throws the error:

> Warning: PDO::__construct(): SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support setting attributes in /var/www/core/class/Banco/GkBanco.php on line 25

I tried  to use:  `setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 10);`  and get the error:

> Warning: PDO::setAttribute(): SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support setting attributes

How to connect with `MSSQL` with a bigger timeout? Can be using any other lib that works with PHP, MSSQL and LINUX.

Comment: There is an answer relating to dblib here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403082/setting-a-connect-timeout-with-pdo