# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I get this error message when i try to connect postgresql via PHP on Windows

```
Warning: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired' in C:\Apache24\htdocs\projetbdd\reconcept.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\projetbdd\reconcept.php(2): PDO->__construct('pgsql:host=loca...', 'postgres', 'momocrosse') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\projetbdd\reconcept.php on line 2

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Apache24\htdocs\projetbdd\reconcept.php on line 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a connect timeout with PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403082/setting-a-connect-timeout-with-pdo)

Answer (score 0):

you can specifies the timeout duration of the connection by use:

```
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 15);
```

form more details see this page:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php