# new PDO request always times out

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to construct a script - `login.php` - which checks whether the entered username exists in the database, then compares whether entered password and password in the database match and is supposed to print the result of these operations on the web page (for now).

First of all the login page:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once("scripts/config.php");
require_once("scripts/helperClass.php");
$username = strip_tags($_POST["username"]);
$password = strip_tags($_POST["password"]);
echo helperClass::checkCredentials($username, $password);
?>
```

Now the helper class: (or at least the relevant function):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
class helperClass {
    public static function checkCredentials($UserName, $Password) {
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".mydbhost.";dbname=".mydbname, myuname, mydbpw);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex) {
            throw(new PDOException($ex->getMessage(), (int) $ex->getCode()));
        }
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT UserId, Password FROM ChatUsers WHERE (? = UserName) OR (? = E_Mail)");
        $statement->execute(array($UserName, $UserName));
        $foundUser = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($foundUser) {
            $pwCorrect = $foundUser["Password"] == $Password;
            if(pwCorrect) {
                $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE ChatUsers SET LoggedIn = true WHERE ? = UserId");
                $statement->execute(array($foundUser["UserId"]));
                return true;
            } 
            else {
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

In `config.php` I define the actual connection data. It compiles fine locally, but then eventually crashes with a `PDOException` as the request timed out. (My PHP editor has pDO support so even locally connection to the external database should work). Online I just get a white screen of death.

I implemented error displaying now, and can see it's working as I get extra notices which were previously silent. Judging from the time the login page takes to load, the SQL query gets executed, but the page still is blank, no errors, no return. Is there anything else I overlooked?

Comment: typos `".mydbhost.";dbname=".mydbname` missing dollar signs in front of `mydbname` and `mydbhost` -> `$mydbhost`, `$mydbname` Same for coming after params `myuname, mydbpw` and in addition those vars where never initialized

Comment: OK... Thanks. Will fix it.

Comment: @alex ah, no. these are not typos. - in config.php( I use define("mydbhost", "whatever.the.host"); etc. no $ sign required for these. Also, where do you see a typo? new PDO("mysql:host=whatever.the.host;dbname="... would be the result...

Comment: no it is still very bad practice. if `mydbname` is a real string constant why don't you just `"mysql:host=mydbhost;dbname=mydbname"`? Why are you using concatenation `.` to join constant strings?

Comment: Turn on error reporting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/296555 and also https://stackoverflow.com/a/14578644/296555

Comment: because config.php is protected, whilst the helper class is not (yet). once I can set dey for all I'll probably change it t your suggestion. for now... I don't think the bad practice is causing aforementioned problem?

Comment: @waterloomatt locally, where error reporting is on, I don't get any errors until the request times out. online i have no access to php.ini.

Comment: OK, thanks. Will do...

Comment: Also, pass options to your connection and set `ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. See here - https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dsn

Comment: updated question.

Comment: `catch(PDOException $ex) {
            throw(new PDOException($ex->getMessage(), (int) $ex->getCode()));` - extremely useless

Comment: Why? That way, it bubbles up to the PHP exception handler, displaying only message and number, no stacktrace - aka no sensitive data. And please, can you do CONSTRUCTIVE criticism? Tell me how to do it better, perhaps?

Comment: Is it timing out on connection or when you execute your statement? You can shorten the timeout period - https://stackoverflow.com/q/21403082/296555

Comment: All good, I fixed it by now. STrATO only permits 4 internal redirects, which apparently was the issue, and all others were just consequences of that initial issue.