# PHP PDO ODBC Connection timeout is not honored

Tags: php, pdo, odbc

I'm after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21403360/881712) answer, and this is my code:

```
<?php    
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$SERVER = "192.168.0.50";
$DATABASE = "MYDB";
const USERNAME = "username";
const PASSWORD = "password";

try {
    $db = new PDO("odbc:MYDB", USERNAME, PASSWORD, 
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 1, // in seconds
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));
    
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">';
    echo "Connection to database failed:" . PHP_EOL . $e->getMessage();
    echo '</div>';
}
```

The remote database is *not* reachable, but despite the timeout setting it takes about 18 seconds to timeout.

I'm using PHP 8.2.4 on Ubuntu 22.04 and ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server.

Comment: Is it the timeout for the connection and/or each query? The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) is unclear, and *“its meaning may differ from driver to driver.”* is vague. This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403082/setting-a-connect-timeout-with-pdo/21403360#comment99530176_21403360) says it's the connection.

Comment: @A.L I'm interested in the connection, actually

Comment: *“The remote database is not reachable”* Please explain this: is an hostname configured? Is the host reachable? I wonder if the DNS resolution or lack of response from the server may take some time.

Comment: @A.L. I'm not using a DNS. As you can see I use an explicit IP address. "It's not reachable" means I put a *wrong* IP address in order to simulate the host is offline. But the behavior is the same when the host is actually offline...